# Find pull requests merged by a specific user

Tags: github

Is it possible to filter pull requests in github by who merged it?

Something like:

```
is:merged is:pr mergedBy:username
```

but that doesn't work

EDIT: 
This was what i came up with (my goal was to create a top list of most active codereviewers in our project):

```
var result = {};
$.get("/api/v3/repos/atg/atgse/pulls?state=closed&per_page=100", function(pulls){
    pulls.forEach(function(listPullItem){
        $.get(listPullItem.url, function(pull) {
            if (pull && pull.merged_by) {
                result[pull.merged_by.login] = result[pull.merged_by.login] || 0;
                result[pull.merged_by.login] ++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Since it doesn't seem to be available directly through the GitHub search filters, you would need to [list the pull request with the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests), and select only the ones with the `merged_by.login` you want.
You have an example in [this coffee script](https://gist.github.com/lonnen/11163857#file-reroy-coffee-L31-L43) which is able to parse the JSON answer and iterate through the pull request entries.